# Default directory is www/php and not www in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

i have my index.html file in c://xampp/htdocs/www

then all my .php files in c://xampp/htdocs/www/php
all my images files in c://xampp/htdocs/www/images
etc

but for some or oher reason it is looking for index.html in c://xampp/htdocs/www/php??
and in my .php files when i want to include a .php file i only have to reference it as

```
include ('functions.php');
```

it should be

```
include ('php/functions.php');
```

how do I set my directories correctly please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `httpd.conf` file and replace the line `DocumentRoot` with the directory path you want.

Comment: thanks this is what i have in httpd.conf

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

Comment: and in httpd-vhost.conf i have: DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/"

Comment: Are these the `.conf` files for XAMPP specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    include("functions.php")

Because you're in the same directory.

If you're using

include ('php/functions.php');

PHP check file in c://xampp/htdocs/www/php/php

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you include the files using absolute path. We can make one config.php inside `www/` directory and in that you can define a constant which has absolute path for your `www/`. Now you can load config.php in bootstrap and use that constant and include required directory files as below

```
config.php

define('ROOT_SYS',dirname(__FILE__).'/'); //$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] for root access

Now in all directory files you can use this to include,

include(ROOT_SYS . 'php/file.php')
```

Comment: thanks but my apache in xampp and my .conf files must be set up correctly. I dont want to do it within my code.